# Input string was not in a correct format from decimal to string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a decimal to a string, this is my code:
i have update the code ,i have textbook view a currency value and not allowed to edit in run time it's just to show the result of other currency numbers .

```
      string sj;
    void calculaer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_SALAIR02.Text)) return;
            mtb_SALAIR02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(mtb_SALAIR02.Text));
            sj = (decimal.Parse(mtb_SALAIR02.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) / 30).ToString();
            mtb_SJ02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(sj));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_SJ02.Text)) return;
            mtb_SJ02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(mtb_SJ02.Text));
            sj = (decimal.Parse(mtb_SJ02.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) * decimal.Parse(mtb_NJ02.Text)).ToString();
            mtb_SM02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(sj));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_SM02.Text)) return;
            mtb_SM02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(mtb_SM02.Text));
            sj = (decimal.Parse(mtb_SM02.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) - decimal.Parse(mtb_AVANCE02.Text) + decimal.Parse(mtb_RELQ02.Text)).ToString();
            mtb_NETPAIE02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(sj));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text)) return;
            mtb_NETPAIE02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0,0#0.00}", decimal.Parse(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text));

            taxe_calc();


            sj = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text)? 0M: decimal.Parse(mtb_NETPAIE02.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_TAXE02.Text)? 0M: decimal.Parse(mtb_TAXE02.Text)).ToString();
            mtb_SAL_TAX02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(sj));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Image of my Code

[image]

Comment: screenshot = useless. We need the value of `sj`

Comment: What is in `sj`?

Comment: Code should never be posted as screenshot because it cannot be copied or indexed by search engines.

Comment: if you check value of sj in debug mode then you'll be able to find the problem by yourself

Comment: The problem seems to be that sj is not a valid formatted decimal.

Comment: please let us know the value of sj variable at that time

Comment: it's a Number , a money number like this 10,000.00

Comment: @wkl: especially if the screenshot doesn't even show the entire line of code... I was going to be helpful and transcribe the code but nope. Not possible. :(

Comment: You have to delete the "," separator. Like this : sj.Replace(",", string.Empty)

Comment: You want us to fix your parse error without showing us what you are parsing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's impossible to help fixing a parsing issue without seeing what was parsed

Comment: @TimSchmelter, No, I think we can fix this issue. Please see my answer below

Comment: Can you explain why sj is a string? You seem to be in every case creating a numeric type and then converting it to a string before then immediately afterwards converting it back to a numeric type... Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it. You should set the culture when you parse. I think your computer are not using standard culture setting.

Don't use CurrentCulture, let change to InvariantCulture or specific culture

```
var result = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse("10,000.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

OR you als can set specific culture if you want

```
var result = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}", decimal.Parse("10,000.00", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-EN")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generally suggest splitting up code, i.e.

```
//decimal dcj = decimal.Parse(sj);
decimal dcj;
if (!decimal.TryParse(sj, out decimal))
{
    throw new ApplicationException("...");
}

mtb_SAL_TAX02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,###,##0.00}",dcj);
```

additionally, if there may be a chance your string representation of decimal could be wrong, I would prefer tryparse.

Comment: the text box should show me the result with this format "99,999,999.99" not like this "9999999999".